# How to merge all paragraphs into a single paragraph when there are other element types in body?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a function that join all the paragraphs of document into a single paragraph. To do so, I'm using the `merge` method this way (`joinAndInsert` variable is a document ID):

```
  if(joinAndInsert){
    Logger.log("joinAndInsert = " + joinAndInsert);
    var paragraphs = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBody().getParagraphs();
    Logger.log("paragraphs = " + paragraphs);
    for (var c=0; c<paragraphs.length; c++){
    var par = paragraphs[c];
      if(par.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
         par.merge();
     }
    var text = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBody().getParagraphs();
    var insertedDoc = DocumentApp.openById(joinAndInsert).editAsText().insertText(0, text);
    }
  }
```

The body of the document sometimes has a `LIST_ITEM` object. And despite my `if` condition, I get a error saying the object has to be the same type to `merge` method work.

Is there any way to convert a `LIST_ITEM` or other type into paragraphs? Is there some alternative way to get this join all paragraphs into one single paragraph task?

Comment: Hello craftApprentice, can you tell me what the finality: do you want to remove everything that's not a paragraph, do you want to extract the text of the whole document, do you want to get everything as HTML (that's a new feature), is the text font and others attributes important for you?

Comment: Hi, @Harold, I just want join all paragraphs into a single big paragraph, preserving the formating (bold words, etc.) of the paragraphs that were joined.

Comment: But what to do with images and drawing, just remove? What about tables and list, merge the their text and ignore their different "placement"?

Comment: Hi, @HenriqueAbreu, these documents has only paragraphs with text (no images and tables) and `LIST_ITEM` also with text. My challenge is to get all this text into a single paragraph preserving its formating (ignoring the "placement". Thanks, guys!

Comment: Sorry craftApprentice, seem that this is not doable. As I don't understand why you want to do something like that, I can't even propose you a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling merge on the first paragraph element might cause an error since there is no previous sibling to merge it with.

If list items are siblings to your paragraphs, that could also cause errors when you call merge. You can avoid that kind of error by keeping track of the previous sibling type in your for loop and only calling merge if the previous sibling is a paragraph element.

<strike>It may be possible to convert your lists into paragraphs by making them into child elements of newly created paragraph elements that take their place. I don't know enough about the google document structure to say for sure whether this is allowed.</strike>

Comment: How implement this "to convert your lists into paragraphs by making them into child elements of newly created paragraph elements that take their place."?

Comment: Never-mind that idea, I checked the API page [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph) and it looks like paragraphs can't have lists as child elements.